# Android adjustResize - How to disable the fade effect

Tags: android, cordova, webview, android-webview

When using **android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"** on a WebView activity its content will resize itself to enable scrolling whenever the user select a text input.

But, every time that the content is resized there is a fade out-in effect.

How can one disable that effect?

Answer (score 1):

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

Maybe it help you.